# How to add one variable each time into the regression model?

Tags: r, variables, regression, paste, lm

I have a question about how to add one variable each time into the regression model to evaluate the adjusted R squared.

For example,

```
lm(y~x1)
```

next time, I want to do

```
lm(y~x1+x2)
```

and then,

```
lm(y~x1+x2+x3)
```

I tried paste, it does not work. for example, `lm(y~paste("x1","x2",sep="+"))`.

Any idea?

Comment: You want the `update` function, which allows you to manipulate formula objects.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you fit 3 variables to your linear regression model: x1, x2 and x3

lm.fit1 = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)

Introducing an additional variable (x4) can be achieved by using the `update` function:

lm.fit2 = update(lm.fit1, .~. + x4)

You could even introduce an interaction term if required:

lm.fit3 = update(lm.fit2, .~. + x2:x3)

Further details on adding variables to regression models can be obtained [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-the-update-function-during-variable-selection/)